# Error: Cannot find module './spawn.js' while running any npm command

Tags: node.js, npm

New to NodeJs and npm, and was just getting started with nodejs, while running any npm command this is the outcome:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install

Error: Cannot find module './spawn.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\revs.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\clone.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\git.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\update-notifier.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ajay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\revs.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
```

I tried multiple npm commands to fix this like:

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install
npm install -g npm@latest
```

But none seems to be working, and all give them the same error, please help!

Comment: After a lot of research, I found the fix for this, actually, there was a problem with the node_modules folder in the path where your npm is installed. Your path will look somewhat like C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm. To find where npm is installed, open cmd and enter "where npm" It will bring up the path to npm, find out node_modules folder and delete it. Then run "npm install", this will again bring up the node_modules folder. That's all, try running npm commands now. If that doesn't work, make sure the path to node js is added to the system environment variable.